# Apache CONNECT request logs - should I be concerned?

Tags: security, apache-2.4, proxy

I was going through my Apache2 access logs this evening, when I found what appear to be CONNECT requests in the log file:

```
...
5*.**.***.**8 - - [28/Jan/2021:21:40:41 +0000] "GET http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MZADjiVIbw?search_query=%EC%95%84%EC%9D%B4%ED%81%B4%ED%83%80%EC%9E%84 HTTP/1.1" 301 565 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR$
5*.**.***.**8 - - [28/Jan/2021:21:40:41 +0000] "CONNECT domain.tldwatch:443 HTTP/1.1" 301 409 "-" "-"
5*.**.***.**8 - - [28/Jan/2021:21:40:43 +0000] "CONNECT domain.tldwatch:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 3817 "-" "-"
5*.**.***.**8 - - [28/Jan/2021:21:40:44 +0000] "CONNECT domain.tldwatch:443 HTTP/1.1" 301 409 "-" "-"
5*.**.***.**8 - - [28/Jan/2021:21:40:44 +0000] "CONNECT domain.tldwatch:443 HTTP/1.1" 200 794 "-" "-"
...
```

This is just one of the requests made, and I've found several more in the logs that are just like this.

As far as I'm aware, I have never touched anything to do with a proxy on my server (i.e. mod_proxy_connect).

Is my server vulnerable? And if so, what steps should I take next, in order to mitigate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These requests look like they were most likely sent a redirect to your actual web site, rather than being proxied to wherever the attacker was trying to go.

To be sure you are not allowing such requests, inspect your Apache configuration for the directive `ProxyRequests`. This is off by default, but some low quality Internet tutorials recommend turning it on to accomplish something else (which it does not). If you turn this on, then it may open your web server to being abused.

As for the requests themselves, it's best practice to keep your web site configuration in its own `<VirtualHost>` and isolated from Apache's default configuration, as shipped by your distribution, which should only return the "It works" page (as a 403 error). Thus any request that doesn't specifically request your domain name will get a 403.